# Como puedo enrutar por parámetros query string en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Deseo saber si es posible y de que forma se podrá enrutar hacia dos diferentes controladores dos rutas en que la única diferencia es que una obtiene un parámetro query string y la otra no, ejemplo:

```
   '/producto' =>  ProductoController@index
   '/producto?id=16' => ProductoController@destalle
```

Sé que se puede hacer por urls amigables de esta forma: '/producto/id' pero deseo saber si laravel puede controlar este tipo de enrutamiento de forma nativa para no realizar todo esto dentro de un controlador y de ahí empezar a enrutar.

Answer (score 2):

Eso lo puedes hacer agregando parámetros a la ruta, sin embargo es recomendable escribir primero la que recibe un parámetro:

```
Route::get('producto?id={id}', 'ProductoController@detalle');
Route::get('producto', 'ProductoController@index');
```

Una mejor opción para la primera línea, asumiendo que el método en tu controlador utilice inyección de dependencias, sería pasar el modelo directamente, de esa forma no tendrás que hacer consultas adicionales y mantener el controlador 'limpio':

```
Route::get('producto/{product}', 'ProductoController@detalle');
```

Esto asume que tu modelo se llama `Product` y que está siendo inyectado en el método `detalle`.

Toda la información está en la documentación de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing

Comment: he intentado la forma que me indicas : `Route::get('producto?id={id}', 'ProductoController@detalle');` y no funciona como se espera se salta a Route::get('producto', 'ProductoController@index'); y muestra el contenido de esta

Comment: Y cuál es el resultado?

Comment: Route::get('producto?id={id}', function(){
    echo "aca con id";
});
Route::get('producto', function(){
    echo "aca solo";
});  

aparece el texto "aca solo" @Shaz

Comment: Asumo que eso quiere decir que intentaste con id y apareció el texto de la segunda línea?

Comment: @VictorRojasCenteno la verdad lo que preguntas no tiene sentido. El query string es para indicar parámetros en la URL. Básicamente, lo que estás haciendo es tener la misma URL mapeada dos veces, por lo cual el framework entiende cosas distintas. Más bien, deberías tener 1 misma ruta y dejar que el controlador defina basado en los valores de tu query string realizar una redirección o algo similar.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza lo que yo deseo es  eso exactamente,  saber si laravel puede enrutar por parámetros en la url para no tomarme el trabajo de enrutar en el controlador como la siguiente opción,  gracias por la respuesta :) .

Comment: @VictorRojasCenteno Pero no entiendo el motivo para no usar la forma de `producto/{product}` y `producto` , eso lo he hecho varias veces sin problema, para enrutar a dos métodos distintos.

Comment: @VictorRojasCenteno primero debes comprender el concepto de la url y de los query strings. Una URL `http://a/b/c` y una URL `http://a/b/c?d=e` son en realidad **la misma URL**, con la diferencia que la segunda tiene parámetros por query string, pero siguen siendo en esencia la misma URL. Ni Laravel ni ningún otro framework irán en contra de ese concepto. Lo que buscas es desafiar a cómo están diseñados los cimientos de los sistemas, cosa que dudo que los frameworks evitarían realizar.

Answer (score 1):

lo que yo haría es: mismaruta/{id?} y en el controller le digo si existe el ID, hago algo, si no existe hago otra cosa ! con el (?) le digo que el parámetro es opcional.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @JuanCarlos. Por favor agrega más detalle en la respuesta, quizás algo de código, de manera que más usuarios puedan beneficiarse de tu explicación.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con la solución pero lo que yo deseo es que se pueda enrutar no mediante url amigables si no por parámetros query string , gracias por la ayuda @juan-carlos-gonzales-q

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('producto', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
  if ($request->get('id')) {
      return redirect()->route('producto.parametro');
  }
  return redirect()->route('producto.sinparametro');
});
```

Comment: Siempre que hagas una respuesta, por mas que sea el código indicado, agrégale un información adicional de que hacer, que no hacer, etc.. Para que los usuarios entiendan un poco mas tu respuesta :D saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los query params de una request en Laravel se utiliza el metod `->get()` :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
   $id = $request->get('id');
   if($id) {
      ...
   }
}
```